# Can I have a mixed es5 / es2015 AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

At my work, we have a large AngularJS app written with ES5 which is planned to migrate very soon. Before migration to any other JS framework (Angular 2+ or React) I would like to take a smaller step migrating the current app to ES2015. ***However, since it's a production large app, it would be more easy if we can handle this migration gradually.***

I know there is a lot of tutorials about AngularJS with ES2015, but I failed to find any which address the situation with mixed ES5 and ES2015 files.

Furthermore, the current ES5 app uses lazy loaded routes with ocLazyload + ui-router, and I'm not sure how this will play with ES2015 module loaders like SystemJS or Webpack.

Any of guys know how to handle this particular scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES2015 is just pure JavaScript with a richer API and a lot of syntactic sugar. For example, when you use a `class` in ES6, this is not a new data structure in the language. This is just syntactic sugar that hide the prototypal nature of JavaScript. Behind the scenes, it is still a function.

So wen you develop an application, you can of course mix ES5 and ES6. If you compile your code with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler), you should have a valid output because ES5 is valid JavaScript.

As you may know, Angular 2 uses [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/). But TypeScript is not like [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/). This is not another language that compiles to JavaScript. Microsoft defines it as a superset of JavaScript. Indeed, if you take a minimal ES5 code and try to compile it with `tsc`, it will work.

So yes, you should be able to do the migration gradually. :)